# how to access a static field defined in BootStrap.groovy from within a service method

Tags: grails

i want to access a static field declared in BootStrap.groovy and initialized in "init" closure, from within a service method. 
BootStrap.nameOfField didn't work.
i get the following error:

im using grails 2.5

Comment: Paste an error and show your code from Bootstrap and from Service.

Comment: Also have you tried the static declaration in a domainClass or src file that then gets access in Bootstrap and service?

Comment: I believe, you should switch the declaration and define the static field in the service so you can read it within `BootStrap`.

Comment: The error was : BootStrap.nameOfField is not a property of the service.  anyway the code now works alternately, i guess its an intellij issue.